# Is there a way to store items?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Can you store your items somehow/somewhere in the Witcher 3?

Like a chest in an inn or whatever?

Comment: Skyrim was the best, on this aspect, I could store items nearly anywhere! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Player stash is being added in version 1.07.

> Adds a stash for player convenience. Players can now store loot in their stash, access to which is available in different parts of the world. Stash locations are marked on the map.

Source: http://thewitcher.com/news/view/1081

Comment: Praise the lord! Now I can actually make all the gear!

Comment: True, you happen to know if/when they will add option to split stocked items, e.g. if I got 10 vials stash only 5 and leave 5 in my inventory?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I no longer play or follow Witcher 3 right now.

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT**

For the sake of updating my answer, the ability to store items was added in [patch v1.07](http://thewitcher.com/news/view/1081).

> Adds a stash for player convenience. Players can now store loot in their stash, access to which is available in different parts of the world. Stash locations are marked on the map.

You can easily find these stash that have a green chest symbol easily spotted on the map. Something like this:

[image: chest location]

The Saddlebags are also important though :D

**OLD VERSION**

**No** you cannot.

So far there is no way of storing your items like you did in The Witcher 2: Assassins of Kings. Maybe CD Projekt RED will include it in an Enhanced Version or in a future Patch.

> Basically to increase your limit of weight carrying you should buy
>   **SaddleBags**

If you want to know about saddlebags there is already a question about this [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/219965/where-can-i-get-some-saddlebags).

Comment: This answer is no longer correct as of patch 1.07

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the article now, but in it the author claimed that simply dropping items on the ground would save them there for the remainder of the game. He suggested finding a nice spot close to a fast travel sign and use that as a loot chest. He said he hadn't lost an item yet.

Edit: there's also a couple of no weight mods out already :) if you're on PC..

Comment: Where are the mods?

Comment: Found them on reddit. Haven't tried them out tho. https://m.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/36n88x/witcher_3_weight_limit_mod/

Comment: Also confirmed on Kotaku, http://kotaku.com/tips-for-playing-the-witcher-3-wild-hunt-1705588522

Comment: Dropping items doesn't work. I tried it and all items vanished after some time.

Answer (score 1):

(ps4 not sure for other systems) I've tried the dropping method and tested it by traveling to other cities and back. Stuff was still all there. Also turning the system off and back on , stuff was still there.

Comment: It's worth noting that this chap (https://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/37fvzi/psa_the_items_you_drop_are_not_safe_despite_what/) suggests that he lost a lot of items using this method. It could have been for many reasons, but worth a bit of caution, perhaps.

Comment: Travelling is pointless. Actual game time pass only when you advance in the main quest, and then you're likely to lose stuff left on the ground.